# How to make fixed div (sticky sidebar) scroll up when it reaches footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help JS experts! I have spent all day trying all the various solutions to similar problems here on StackOverflow - none of them do exactly what I want.

I have a dynamic height sidebar that becomes fixed when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the sidebar (the page content is often longer than the sidebar). This is so that the bottom half of the sidebar stays visible when the user keeps reading the content.

The problem is now the sidebar runs into the footer at the bottom of the page. Since the sidebar is longer than the view port, it cannot simply become position:relative again. It needs to scroll up with the footer (which has a dynamic height as well, to add to the complication).

I made an image (that it won't let me post here because I'll be damned if I know how to increase my reputation.) https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDk1Z.jpg

What I'd like to happen is find a syntactically correct way of saying:

```
When scrollTop >= Height of Footer + 20px margin {
    add CSS "bottom: <Height of Footer + 20px margin>" to SIDEBAR };
```

Thanks in advance for all who try to help!

Comment: Surely someone must know how to do this? I cannot believe I've asked a question that stumps everyone at SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic ways to do this:

1. **Right way:** fix the HTML so that the scroll bar's parent is contained in something that spans from the bottom of the header to the top of the footer.  This way everything just works out.

Code:

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="main">
    <!-- possibly overflown stuff, maybe your fake scrollbar if you have one -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

If you can make this work, this will be the best way by far.

2. **Less-Right Way:** I think this only possible with variable size scrollbar made of a `div` or similar. Use something like:

Code:

```
element-that-scrolls.addEventListener("scroll",function(e){
    // this condition may need some fiddling -- feel free to edit
   if (element-that-scrolls.scrollTop > scrollable-height + pixel-height-of-footer - height-of-scrollbar - required-margin-btw-footer-and-scrollbar){
       /* adjust height of scrollbar until previous condition is == */
    }
},false);
```

Unfortunately I am on my phone and can't test these, but as I commented, feel free to edit.

Fun fact I just learned:  the "code:" is necessary due to a markdown bug.  [See more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23822/markdown-code-block-problem).